# 2 EditText + 2 TextWatcher - stackoverflow error

Tags: android, android-edittext, stack-overflow, textwatcher

I have 2 EditText + 2 TextWatcher, one EditText affects the another. 
I struggle with this and don't have idea how to avoid StackOverFlow error,

why edit_stezenie_ldl.removeTextChangedListener(watch) is not enough? It should stop this TextWatcher.

```
 @Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
     watch = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if( edit_stezenie_ldl.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                edit_stezenie_ldl2.setText(null);
            }
            else {

                String x  = edit_stezenie_ldl.getText().toString();
                Double xy = Double.parseDouble(x) / (36.8);
                Double rounded = round(xy, 2);
                String wynik = rounded.toString();
                edit_stezenie_ldl2.setText(wynik);

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
    watch2 = new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if( edit_stezenie_ldl2.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                edit_stezenie_ldl.setText("");
            }
            else {

                String x  = edit_stezenie_ldl2.getText().toString();
                Double xy = Double.parseDouble(x) / (36.8);
                Double rounded = round(xy, 2);
                String wynik = rounded.toString();
                edit_stezenie_ldl.setText(wynik);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    };

    if(v==edit_stezenie_ldl && hasFocus){
             edit_stezenie_ldl2.removeTextChangedListener(watch2);
             edit_stezenie_ldl.addTextChangedListener(watch);
    }
    else if(v==edit_stezenie_ldl2 && hasFocus){

            edit_stezenie_ldl.removeTextChangedListener(watch);
            edit_stezenie_ldl2.addTextChangedListener(watch2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeTextChangedListener()` does not remove the `TextWatcher` because it's not the same `watch` object as when you added the listener, since you redefine your `TextWatcher` every time when `onFocusChange()` is called. Thus no listener is ever removed and on every focus change, you add new listener, which all call each other when a text change occurs, ending in a StackOverflowError.

I'd suggest to instantiate the two `TextWatcher` objects somewhere outside of `onFocusChange()` so they get created only once.

Or alternatively you only instantiate the listener when they are `null`:

```
if (watch == null) {
    watch = new TextWatcher() {
        ...
    };
}
if (watch2 == null) {
    watch2 = new TextWatcher() {
        ...
    };
}
```

Comment: Oh my god :) I've tried to instantiate TextWatcher somewhere else, but it wasn't working for some strange reason, and now did it again and works great! Thank you @Floern!